# Div display:none - want to only load content when it's visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a series of divs with images as backgrounds, fairly large images at that, 1-2 MBs.

What I'd like to do is only load the content within them when they're visible.

(They're display:none by default and onclick of various links I use jquery to slide them down/up).

Comment: be aware that you cannot have your cake and eat it - if the image isn't already loaded, it's going to look rubbish if you try and slide it in, not least because a) it'll be a partial image, and b) the DOM may not know what size the image is supposed to be yet.

Comment: My work around was to place them in image tags, hide the divs and open them onclick of a link.
Then I used lazy load to load the images, since that only loads images that are visible - thus I get reduced page load time, less server load and my slide down animation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a rough sketch of an idea which might work. Create hidden image tags for each of the photos you want to load, attaching onload event handlers directly. `insert` simply takes the image which just loaded and creates a css `background` rule to be inserted into the appropriate `div`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js' type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      div.placeHolder {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>


  <img  data-id='imageA' 
        src='http://some-large-image.jpg' 
        style='display:none;' 
        onload='insert(this);' />

  <div data-id='imageA' class='placeHolder' style='display:none;'></div>

  <script>
    function insert(img){
      $img = $(img);
      $div = $('div.placeHolder[data-id='+$img.attr('data-id')+']');
      var cssSnippet = "transparent url("+ $img.attr('src') +") no-repeat 0 0";
      $div.css('background', cssSnippet).show();
    }
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

you should post your code, but I think this might be what you are looking for.

html

```
<a href="#">Link to click</a>
<div id="imgname"></div>
```

jquery

```
$('a').click(function(){
 $('div#imgname').html('<img src="image.path" />');
});
```

send html and slide the div block down

```
<a href="#">Link to click</a>
<div id="imgname"><img src="image.path" /></div>
```

Comment: and there's zero AJAX involved there - that's just image "post loading"

Comment: The divs are hidden by default

<a class="inlinkp" href="#viewwork" onclick="javascript:slideonlyone('galleryone');">Link here</a>

Moves the page to where the gallery is via anchor tag and this :-

<script type="text/javascript">
function slideonlyone(thechosenone) {
     $('div[class|="newboxes2"]').each(function(index) {
          if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {
               $(this).slideDown(2000);
          }
          else {
               $(this).slideUp(2000);
          }
     });
}
</script>

Slides down the divs as the link is clicked.

Comment: that will work too! there are so many ways to mix css and js to create the same effects. slide up and down will work better if that is all you are doing with it.

Comment: No no, I want it NOT to load the content inside the div that slides up and down until it's viewed, hence reducing page load time.
I intend to have dozens of these on the same page so I need to load only when viewed.